# How to split single PPPoE connection into two but use one at a time?

Tags: networking, router, pppoe, splitter

I want to split my **PPPoE** connection into two ethernet cables to connect with two routers, `Router A` and `Router B`. But, I will use one router at a time to log in to PPPoE.

The reason is, `Router A` will run only when electricity goes away and rest of the time `Router B` will be on and working. I could keep switching the **RJ45 connector** from one router two another but that's not a permanent solution. Is there a way to split a single PPPoE connection into two? Will a **Ethernet/RJ45 splitter** work here?

Answer (score 1):

A splitter will let you connect two routers, but the PPPoE I have used will expect the same router to remake the broken connection.

Further your second router here cannot be connected live to your network. It will act (default) as a second DHCP server. Turning DHCP off means devices cannot connect to it.

So having a second router will not work as a failover here.

Best to provide Router B with a small UPS.

True failover requires 2 ISPs connected to a router that provides failover capability.

Comment: I have set same MAC address in both routers by MAC cloning. Will the PPPoE still expect the same router to remake the connection?

Comment: It might but I have not seen that. Two routers with the same MAC may also cause issues on the LAN side of the routers (2 DHCP servers and connection issues).

Answer (score 0):

PPP means point-to-point, that means it is intended that only one device at your side uses the ethernet link.
You can't split the PPP connection.
Those RJ45 splitters are to use the 2 unused wire pairs (10/100 MBit/s doesn't need them) for a separate ethernet connection if only one cable is available.
Those are not suitable for your problem here.

I recommend a UPS for one router, so it is connected at any time.

If you really need 2, connect a switch, but make sure you only turn on one router at the same time.